# CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES vs.nvidia-smi disagreement on GPU id?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia

I recently did an apt-get upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, and one of the things it did was grab a revised nvidia-375 package, and I notice now that if I run a process as

$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 ./myprocess

it actually shows up on nvidia-smi as running on GPU 1, and similarly if I run

$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 ./myprocess

nvidia-smi shows the process as running on GPU 0.   This is the opposite behavior of what I was getting before the update, and seems opposite of what's described on [a common reference on CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES](http://www.acceleware.com/blog/cudavisibledevices-masking-gpus).

Is there a "fix" for this?  It's not a major inconvenience, but it would be nice to have some consistency.

.

PS- I'm not aware of any other NVIDIA-related "issues" on my system since I did this upgrade, just the GPU id switch.

Comment: You may be able to adjust it with [an environment variable](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars), specifically `CUDA_​DEVICE_​ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID`, which should force CUDA to enumerate devices in the same order as `nvidia-smi`

Comment: That works!  Thanks.  If you make your comment an "answer," I'll give you my vote!